# preload some libraries and scripts in python

Tags: python

How to preload some libraries and scripts in python before I call python command? Is there something like .bashrc file to deal with predefining some functions/variables before launching a shell terminal?

Thanks.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: No, I just want to know if there is some facility with the language so that I do not need to do `import math` etc. every time I use python command.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50454957/preload-a-py-file-into-python-3-enviroment

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create a file, 'my_imports.py' and add the import lines for all your modules.

```
import math
import anothermodule
import anotherothermodule
```

Then set an environment variable 'PYTHONSTARTUP' and set it to '/path/to/my_imports.py'.

Now when you run python at the command prompt, it will load your modules first.

Comment: how about when I have multiple .py files that I need to import too?

Comment: To import my_file.py, just add 'import my_file' to the file above it will need to be in the same directory, or your site_packages directory.

Answer (score 2):

i wanted to sometimes run python with a bunch of statistics/math stuff loaded (numpy, matplotlib, etc), but othertimes just a simple python without having the overhead of loading modules i wasn't going to use.

i use ubuntu linux, so i created a python script `python-preload.py` with the following:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
```

and added an alias to my `~/.bashrc`:

```
alias pym='PYTHONSTARTUP=/home/$USER/path/to/script/python-preload.py python'
```

so when i want normal python i run `python`, and when i want all the math stuff i run `pym`.

hope this helps. based off Tony Blundell's answer.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
python -i -c "import math"
```

And you can put this into a bash file, like b.sh

```
#! /bin/bash

python -i -c "import math"
```

Then you can set whatever you want.