# How to import math module for all Python sessions by default on Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python, math, module, visual-studio-code

I am using V.S. Code as a Python (v3.7.1) editor.
I use the `import math` to access modules functions.

Every time I start a new instance of Python I have to import the math module.

Is there any way I can permanently import/install the math module to avoid having to import it every time I start a new Python session?

Comment: Possible duplicate?
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9712064/preload-some-libraries-and-scripts-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9712064/preload-some-libraries-and-scripts-in-python)